# In Shakespeare, besides "ponderous and marble jaws," are there any similarly structured phrases?

Tags: shakespeare

There are better ways to word this question, I'm sure, but I can't think of any for some reason: my apologies.

In *Hamlet*, Act 1, Scene 4, the lead character speaks as follows:

> Let me not burst in ignorance, but tell
> Why thy canonized bones, hearsed in death,
> Have burst their cerements; why the sepulcher,
> Wherein we saw thee quietly interred,
> Hath oped his **ponderous and marble jaws**
> To cast thee up again.

Shakespeare's taking liberties with usage (or inventing usage as he went along) is well known. Some of the instances (such as this one) may or may not be beautiful, but they certainly stick in your memory.

One certainly wouldn't expect "marble" to follow "ponderous and ..." because ... hmm ...

Well, because there is a bunch of adjective categories (some say thirteen), and different categories should not be separated by a conjunction. As in, a descriptive or qualitative adjective ("ponderous" in this case) followed by a material or participial adjective ("marble" in this case) should not be separated by a conjunction ("and"). As in -

... red and riding hood ...
... antique and wooden table ...

... and so forth.

Except that Shakespeare's example, odd as it may sound, sets up camp in your memory. Deservedly so, I hasten to add.

My question is:

Can you recall any other such phrases in Shakespeare's works?

(Bonus question: is there an official term for this type of grammatical and/or usage error?)

UPD:

Tevildo just provided another example in the comments, from *Macbeth*, Act 4, Scene 1:

> How now, you **secret, black, and midnight hags**!

More examples, please!

Comment: [There **are** a bunch] You can use the Searchable Shakepeare for this. It is not an error. Where did you find that "rule"? Poe, The Raven: For *the rare and radiant maiden* whom the angels name Lenore—Lewis Carroll The Hunting of the Snark: **A perfect and absolute blank**!" [Next?]

Comment: Sap cheque'd with **frost and lusty leaves** quite gone, Shakespeare, Sonnet Five

Comment: Last one:  Make **glad and sorry seasons** as thou fleets,5
And do whate'er thou wilt, swift-footed Time, Also the Bard, Sonnet 19 For the plays, you will have to plough through them yourself.

Comment: There's a name for this type of play on words, but it escapes me now.

Comment: Meter definitely plays a role here in the presence of "and".

Comment: @Barnar: please try to recall!

Comment: @StuartF: Of course it does. But that's not the point.

Comment: @Barmar It is not a play on words.

Comment: It's a *mild* form of ***zeugma***

Comment: @FumbleFingers: kind of. Are there any other instances that come to mind? (In Shakespeare, I mean)?

Comment: Wikipedia: a figure of speech in which one word applies to two others in different senses of that word, and in some cases only logically applies to one of the other two words. How is that zeugma here? What it is, is description, at best a metaphor: His jaws are large and bulky and hard like marble.

Comment: [Hyperbaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbaton) would be the term if Shakespeare were writing in Latin (_Robor et aes triplex_), but, unfortunately, the term has a different meaning when applied to English.

For another example: "How now, you **secret, black, and midnight** hags!" (_Macbeth_, Act 4, Scene 1).

Comment: @Tevildo: Excellent! Thank you! Got more?

Comment: @lambie Zuegma what I was thinking of, but I guess I misunderstood what Shakespeare was trying to say. I assumed "ponderous jaws" and "marble jaws" were two metaphors using different senses of "jaw".

Comment: @Tevildo Be careful, or someone may clobber you with their large and menacing *hyperbaton*! ;-)

Comment: *hendiadys* could also apply.

Comment: @Robusto: That's brilliant, sir!

Answer (score 1):

There are two factors that in general can be at play here. One is just the twinning of adjectives (in general, premodifiers) so semantically incongruous that the result is ludicrous.

- *An expensive sharpened pencil*.

This is not the case here with 'ponderous' and 'marble'. But the string 'secret, black, and midnight' is a different matter.

The other is that the conjunction 'and' is normally only used between a certain type of  pairing of adjectives (and adjective / attributive noun pairs):

> - Coordinate adjectives are separated by a comma and sound fine if you change their order or insert “and” between them instead of a comma.
> - Cumulative adjectives are not separated by a comma and must be placed in a specific order based on their category [and don't sound
>   fine if "and" is inserted].

[[Writing Fundamentals Guide](https://writing-fundamentals-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lesson5-coordinateadjs/#:%7E:text=Coordinate%20adjectives%20are%20separated%20by,order%20based%20on%20their%20category.)]

'*Hath oped his ponderous and marble jaws*' or

'*Has opened his ponderous marble jaws*'

sounds awful if the modifiers are reversed

*'*Has opened his marble ponderous jaws*'.

So the order is invariant, and using an 'and' between the premodifiers non-standard.

Comment: "[It was a dark and stormy night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_was_a_dark_and_stormy_night)."

Comment: Yes; fixed expressions can play havoc with the 'rules'. 'The wild and woolly west' sounds bad without the 'and'.

Answer (score 1):

Can you say iambic pentameter? <sub><sup>← Hint: That’s ten syllables.</sup></sub>

> Most of Shakespeare’s characters speak in what is called “blank
> verse.” It contains no rhyme, but each line has an internal rhythm
> with a regular rhythmic pattern. The pattern most favored by
> Shakespeare is iambic pentameter. Iambic pentameter is defined as a
> ten-syllable line with the accent on every other syllable, beginning
> with the second one. The rhythm of this pattern of speech is often
> compared to a beating heart.
>  <sub>Source: [Utah Shakespeare
> Festival — Hamlet: Examining the
> Text](https://www.bard.org/study-guides/hamlet-examining-the-text/)</sub>

I’m not saying that the *and* in *ponderous and marble jaws* is wrong or that it’s just there for syllable count but, yeah, you’re going to find a lot of that. Count ’em up:

> / Hath / oped / his / pon / der / ous / and / mar / ble / jaws
>
> / How / now / you / se / cret / black / and / mid / night / hags

<sub>See also: [ThoughtCo — Examples of Iambic Pentameter in Shakespeare’s Plays](https://www.thoughtco.com/iambic-pentameter-examples-2985081)</sub>

Comment: I'm well aware that it scans just fine. That wasn't the question. +1 anyway, thank you.

Comment: For the _Macbeth_ quotation, something like "secret, cursed, midnight hags" would fit the meter without employing the figure of speech.  I'm sure that Shakespeare used the "and" deliberately.

Comment: As a quick follow-up, here's a negative example from _Hamlet_ - "Thy **knotted and combined** locks to part".  "And" here is just a normal conjunction; it's essential to the meter, but it doesn't have the striking quality of - unorthodoxy - that's seen in the other examples.

Comment: The *and* is not an error, and it’s used for meter. Was that not your question?

Comment: @TinfoilHat: No, the question was, "In Shakespeare, besides "ponderous and marble jaws," are there any similarly structured phrases?"

Comment: @ricky you're giving me very strong pretentious vibes like you're very impressed with yourself and your own writing "style". Just FYI. I'm sure you don't want to come off as pretentious, so just trying to help.